# Movement angle issue in phaser 3

Tags: phaser-framework

check [this](http://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src/physics%5Carcade%5Cspace.js) lab example out.
It actually only moves in 4 angles (45,135,-45,-135). How to fix this?

---Update---

yes it starts to move in all angles but then it start to dragging to one of those 4 angles I said. if you active debug mode and just move in one angle except the ones I said you will notice it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vpo7w.jpg)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by moving in 4 angles. The all game objects (ship, bullets, particles) move nicely, definitely more than 4 angles. Please explain more.

Comment: @JaeMinIm I updated my post please check it. you can see in image that particle angle is -135 although I'm moving to 90.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah ha! I got it. This is really weird part of Phaser.

When Phaser set maximum velocity of 600,
it doesn't set vector velocity maximum 600.

But instead, it would set **velocity.x and velocity.y maximum to 600**

Meaning, because the ship accelerates over the maximum,

it will reach velocity.x = 600 and velocicty.y = 600,
causing it to move in 45, -45,...etc.

I remember this from phaser 2, and I solved with my own maximum function.
Here is my (sort of) pseudo code.

```
function maximumVelocity(sprite, maxV){
  var v = Math.sqrt( Math.pow(sprite.body.velocity.x,2) + Math.pow(sprite.body.velocity.y,2) )
  if(v > maxV){
    sprite.body.velocity.x = maxV * Math.cos(sprite.angle*Math.PI/180)
    sprite.body.velocity.y = maxV * Math.sin(sprite.angle*Math.PI/180)
  }
}
```

EDIT:
I accidentally added square of x twice. I should have added x^2 and y^2.
And also, I just wrote a complete working code, instead of psudo one.

Comment: I have a same problem and I can't make your code work, maybe because it's for phaser 2? can you take a look? (I tried it with the above lab example)

Comment: @adamWest sure. If you post your code here(or pm), I can take a look. Probably it’s not working because my code above is psudocode. I’m not sure which is correct between: sprite.angle or sprite.body.angle. (And you have to convert degree/radians for trigs). But my logic is there.

Comment: I just tried your code with this lab example:http://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src/physics%5Carcade%5Cspace.js

. but `if(v > maxV)` is never true

Comment: @adamWest I had a small error in my code. Please check my edited code above. I just tested my code, and it works.